# Custom preference page - opt outs reflected in All Subscribers list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, unsubscribe

We are using a custom preference page where our subscribers can change channel / communication preferences and opt-out from all communication. However, due to human error, sometimes some of the unsubscribes on our Master List receive a newsletter. To avoid this, we would like an opt-out on our Master List to upsert the AllSubscribers list's status to unsubscribed. Is there a way to do this (AMPscript or some other way)? Tnx

Comment: It depends on how you are updating your master list, if this update is happening at a code level you could also include AMPScript to update the all subscriber list or alternatively you could run an automation that determines the records that fit the unsubscribe criteria via SQL and import that result in to the all subscribers with a Status of Unsubscribed.

Comment: I understand the ampscript might be the more elegant way to go, but regarding the second option with SQL, can the import status to All Subscribers step be done automatically somehow?

Comment: Yes you can populate a Data Extension with data from your master data extension and the status "unsubscribed". Then you can have a data extract of that DE and import it to the all subscribers list using automation studio.

Comment: DonL, it worked out. Although, All Subscribers status requries is very picky when it comes to how data extension is named and structured... but it worked :)